# php reach functions from a extended class through the parent class

Tags: php

I've been searching around the net for answers but couldn't find anything relevant, so I thought about asking it here.

How can I reach functions from a extended class through it's parent class?

**Base (parent class)**

```
require_once('FirstChild.class.php');

require_once('SecondChild.class.php');

class Base {

public $first;

public $second;


function __construct() {

$this->first = new FirstChild();

$this->second = new SecondChild();

}

}
```

**First (child class)**

```
class FirstChild extends Base {

public $firstVar;


function __construct() {

$this->firstVar = 'Hello';

}


public function getSecondVar() {

echo parent::$second->getVar();//doesnt work!!?

}

}
```

**Second (child class)**

```
class SecondChild extends Base {

public $secondVar;


function __construct() {

$this->secondVar = 'World';

}


public function getVar() {

return $this->secondVar;

}

}
```

**How can the "getSecondVar" function be reached inside "FirstChild"?**

Thanks!

Comment: self::method() or static::method()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `parent::` method. Instead use `$this->second->getVar();` and make sure the parent constructor is called as well, e.g. with `parent::__construct();` (alternatively, populate $this->second in your `FirstChild` constructor)

E.g.

```
class FirstChild extends Base {
    public function __construct() {
        // your code
        $this->second = new SecondChild();
        $this->firstVar = 'Hello';
    }
    public function getSecondVar() {
        echo $this->second->getVar();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Also the way you've set it up, `$second` would never be set as by adding the constructor method to `FirstChild`, you are overriding `Base::__construct()`. You'll either need to recall `parent::__construct()` and make sure it doesn't create a new instance of `FirstChild()` or you need to do the same code within `FirstChild`'s constructor.

Anyway, it's usually not best practice to be calling child classes from a parent class.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems to loop between the classes over and over again and I'm getting: Fatal error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20 bytes) in Base.php on line 10

Comment: My bad, in this case you need to make sure that you don't call up the `FirstChild` in `parent::__construct()`. and instead call up only `SecondChild` within `FirstChild::__construct()`. See updated code

Answer (score 0):

You read about how to reach a parents class function and it works with the [`parent` keyword](http://php.net/keyword.parent) like so:

```
parent::__construct();
```

For the property `$second` you can just access with `$this` as it is public:

```
$this->second;
```

And that's already all. Take care you call the parent's constructor and keep in mind that public members are public (and you will never be able to reach private members).